# How to add EFI GOP driver to platform firmware for use with Secure Boot?

Tags: drivers, installation, bios, uefi, efi

I am trying to insert a GOP driver for the SM750 embedded graphics chip into the platform firmware so that it can be used with secure boot.  This is in the form of an .efi file that was given to me by the manufacturer so it their "official" GOP driver.  Currently, I am using a .rom version of this driver by loading it into an EEPROM attached to the SM750 using an executable program in DOS that they also provided. I have been told this .rom file cannot be used with Secure Boot so I have been looking at ways to insert the .efi version of this driver into the firmware.

Reading section 32 of the [EDK2 Firmware guide] (https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-uefi-driver-writer-s-guide/32_distributing_uefi_drivers/) states there are 3 ways to insert into the platform.

1. PCI option ROM

I believe this is how the .rom version of the driver is being loaded currently, since this is connected to the PCI bus and this would probably be the ideal way of doing this with the .efi driver, but I do not know a way that I can put the .efi file onto this EEPROM

2. Through the platform flash

I would rather avoid this method if I can, I do not want to use a custom image from the manufacturer

3. On an EFI partition in the hard drive

I thought this would be the way to do it, but after reading into it more it seems that this would only be viable for updates and not for loading the driver on boot.  Correct me if I'm wrong with this, but this would also only execute when the OS is loaded from the EFI partition (in this case RHEL7).

The CPU is a Xeon D-1559 and the target OS is RHEL7.6

TL;DR what is the best way to insert an efi GOP driver into a system for use with secure boot.

Comment: Generally, .efi files are bootloaders for efi-based bootup (which includes secure boot). It wouldn't be loaded into the devices eeprom but rather stored on the EFI partition on the hard drive where the UEFI bios could find it and let you select it as a boot option. That said, it could just be a poorly chosen extension by the manufacturer.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Even if this file is a video driver? I would need video out somehow before getting to the EFI partition on a hard drive. Even if I don't "boot" from the this file in the traditional sense, would the system know to look for in the EFI partition for drivers to load?

Comment: The SOP on PC (x86/_64 platforms in general) is for the video adapter to support certain highly standardized video modes specifically to allow video out during the POST and boot process. It's unclear to me if this is the case for the SM750... however, assuming the file really is an EFI bootloader, then it _isn't_ a video driver... it's an image containing the machine code needed to bootstrap an OS... including any low-level drivers necessary for that task (specialty storage controllers and video hardware, for example). But that's a hypothetical. Like I said, the exention could be misleading.

Comment: The point I'm making is that there are some things in what you've said that make me wonder if perhaps you have some of the details incorrect. Might not. Just trying to give you a heads up that you might want to double check the facts so far and be sure you haven't gotten anything mixed up.

Comment: You may be right, I have never dealt with GOP drivers before, I was just stating what I understood from trying to look into this more.  Currently, when a .rom version of the driver is loaded into the EEPROM attached to the chip, I get video out.  Before that, there is nothing.  My thinking was that since the .rom and .efi version are just differently compiled version of the same source (said by manufacturer) that they would behave in at least similar ways.  I could be wrong in thinking this.

Comment: My question, I guess is, would the "correct" thing to try is loading this file into the EFI partition and "boot" from it?  Would this tell the system to display video, even in the pre-OS phase? And I just want to make sure that doing this won't mess with the CPU/UEFI image in any way.  I really appreciate you helping me with this

Comment: Can you provide more information about which graphics card you have? I bought an EGPV-1101-W1 M.2 video card, booted it in a computer that supported VBIOS, and flashed the UEFI-compatible firmware that Innodisk provided, but after flashing the card was not usable at all in either VBIOS or UEFI systems. I am very curious to know if anyone else has tried this and gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1):

So the manufacturer provided you the rom file as well as the efi file?
Generally 'rom' files are binary firmware files directly flashable to BIOS chips of an add-in component and lives in the chip. They are standalone files and overwrites the previous version when flashed.

OptionROMs are the BIOS driver for Legacy/CSM Boot and is a small portion embedded in the MB BIOS chip. They are not circulated as user upgradable stand alone files to the end-user. But advanced users can but is not supported by the manufacturers.

AFAIK, if you need secure boot (form of advanced UEFI boot, class 3, sometimes called true UEFI boot), the GOP driver has be present in the MB BIOS chip or the BIOS chip of the external PCI card attached. Secureboot is possible when all 'core devices' have a EFI driver in the BIOS. Generally in a native UEFI boot environment, 'efi' files are drivers loaded by a UEFI boot loader(BL) [OS] / boot manager(BM) [like Grub or rEFInd] for booting secondary/peripherals functions, and not for core IO function like display output.

But I guess that efi file can also be used as a 'loadable driver' when you are trying to run an emulated UEFI (like DuetPkg, tianocore) on old systems which were made for legacy boot only. There may be some clever BM/BL out there which can inject the rom/efi file before an emulated UEFI boot. But they can only achieve an emulated UEFI boot and not a secure boot (which is what your manufactured also stated, so they knew something about the limitation of the board/device). I hope my reply shall bring you closer to the correct solution.